# Puppet agent hangs on Loading facts from

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

## Info

```
root@slx04c-8odu:/home/xiaojguan# which puppet
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/puppet
root@slx04c-8odu:/home/xiaojguan# puppet -V
3.8.6
root@slx04c-8odu:/home/xiaojguan# facter -v
1.7.5
root@slx04c-8odu:/home/xiaojguan# ll /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/
total 188
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 25  2021 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Nov 22  2020 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   430 Nov 22  2020 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   916 Nov 22  2020 asset.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3842 Nov 22  2020 bmc.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   620 Nov 22  2020 broadcast.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    66 Nov 22  2020 check_nsx_manager.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   627 Nov 22  2020 cidr.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1683 Feb 25  2021 cloudnative.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   581 Nov 22  2020 core_count.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1016 Nov 22  2020 default_gateway.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   294 Nov 22  2020 default_route.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1250 Nov 22  2020 dhcp_server.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4313 Nov 22  2020 disks.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   305 Nov 22  2020 efi.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1116 Nov 22  2020 esx.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4667 Nov 22  2020 facter_dot_d.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   236 Nov 22  2020 ip6tables_version.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   444 Nov 22  2020 iptables_persistent_version.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   234 Nov 22  2020 iptables_version.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1792 Nov 22  2020 metadisks.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   374 Nov 22  2020 my-vars.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   183 Nov 22  2020 nameserver.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6228 Nov 22  2020 nics.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   542 Nov 22  2020 nvidia_3d.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   114 Nov 22  2020 nvidia_product_id.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   564 Nov 22  2020 ovs_client_cert.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1172 Nov 22  2020 pe_version.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184 Nov 22  2020 proc_mounts.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   620 Nov 22  2020 processor_frequency.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   937 Nov 22  2020 puppet_vardir.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20125 Nov 22  2020 raid.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   875 Nov 22  2020 root_home.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   213 Nov 22  2020 service_daemon_helper.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   618 Nov 22  2020 staging_http_get.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   251 Nov 22  2020 staging_windir.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   149 Nov 22  2020 swap_file_exists.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   790 Nov 22  2020 swapon_size.rb
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 22  2020 util/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   146 Nov 22  2020 var_mb.rb
```

## Problem description

When I run `puppet agent -t --debug --verbose` on `ubuntu 20.04` it just hangs at this stage:

```
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/esx.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/asset.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/nvidia_product_id.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/core_count.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/efi.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/nvidia_3d.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/disks.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/swapon_size.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/nics.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/service_daemon_helper.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/cidr.rb
```

I use strace to trace the process and got this:

```
root@slx04c-7tgb:/var/lib/puppet/lib# strace -p $(ps aux | grep applying | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2}')
strace: Process 13250 attached
select(10, [9], [], NULL, NULL
```

## Things I tried

1. change the directory `var/lib/puppet/lib/facter` and rerun the puppet agent with these commands:

   ```
   mv /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter-bak
   puppet agent -t --debug --verbose
   ```

## Expectation

1. how to know which snippet of code is stuck
2. how to make the puppet agent okay to run

## Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your puppet version and facter version. Do you have custom facts? Has this even gone past the hanging?

Comment: Add info of puppet and facter, and found facter files in `/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/`

Comment: I run `facter` is ok and respond very quickly.

Comment: The starve sitting on "select" suggests it may be waiting on something on the network.  Select is used to wait for data to arrive.

Comment: It is ok to connect to the puppet server